# How can I align submenu behind content with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I align the submenu (activated on hover) behind the content, on this page:
http://tinyurl.com/pmuj43q

The page title "Center Info" is always in front of the submenu when you hover over the navigation menu item called "Center Info"

I implemented the css3 menu from this link: http://www.cssscript.com/3d-flipping-dropdown-navigation-with-pure-css3/

Comment: I'm not sure this 100% answers your question, but the css `z-index` property should fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a `z-index` to your header to pull it above the rest of the content...

```
header#masthead {
  /* rest of styles */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I tried playing with z-index on sever elements, adding position: relative is what made it finally work.